# Image not loading from startup

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have this code im using on my website but the image does not load when page opens, I want the image to load from start up then a simple mouse over to change image and a link when clicked. Im not good at coding so any help would be good.

here is the code im using.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <body>
 <head>
  <script>
    function init() {
        setImageOne();
    }

    function setImageOne() { setImage('http://earthbounds.com/banners/amazing food.jpg'); }

    function setImageTwo() { setImage('http://earthbounds.com/banners/amazing food 2.jpg'); }

    function setImage(src) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("e");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if (context == null) return;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = src;
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 322, 200);
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

No Canvas Support in Browser

Comment: If you don't have Canvas support in your browser why are you calling a canvas js method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the image to load before you draw it. Also, if your browser doesn't support canvas nothing will help you with this approach.

```
function setImage(src) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("e");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    if (context == null) return;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 322, 200);
    };
    img.src = src;

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but when i used the extra bit of code you gave me the image will not load at all now.

Comment: I edited my answer. Sorry, you have to set the callback before setting the source.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the image to load. Thus your code should be (with corrections regarding html markup):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="e" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
  <script>
    function init() {
        setImageOne();
    }

    function setImageOne() { setImage('http://earthbounds.com/banners/amazing food.jpg'); }

    function setImageTwo() { setImage('http://earthbounds.com/banners/amazing food 2.jpg'); }

    function setImage(src) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("e");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if (context == null) return;
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function (){
            context.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
        };
        img.src = src;
    }
    init();
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This only works in browsers that support canvas ex: Chrome(ium)

Also I suggest you read [this](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first method you tried? If you are just trying to add an image on a website and a hover over it there is a much simpler way.

First off, instead of using Javascript to create and load an Image, use the HTML `<img>` tag, example:

```
<img src="http://earthbounds.com/banners/amazing food.jpg">
```

Now to add a simple hover image change, this is not the best practice but for an example, and for a single image you can use `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`, example:

```
<img src="http://earthbounds.com/banners/amazing food.jpg" onmouseover="this.src('http://earthbounds.com/banners/amazing food 2.jpg')" onmouseout="this.src('http://earthbounds.com/banners/amazing food.jpg')">
```

Now to make this image a link to another page, or website you use the `<a>` tag, example:

```
<a href="www.google.ca"><img src="http://earthbounds.com/banners/amazing food.jpg" onmouseover="this.src('http://earthbounds.com/banners/amazing food 2.jpg')" onmouseout="this.src('http://earthbounds.com/banners/amazing food.jpg')"></a>
```

Hope this helps, and keep looking and learning!

Comment: Dylan N, Actually the code you gave me just now was my first choice but couldn't get it to work so I decided that html5 canvas might be better. I copied the code you gave me exactly but It also doesn't seem to work.